# Prevent data-code interleaving in C++

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

I have compiled a binary in which there is a function including some data. Apparently the jump table entries in the switch statement are embedded within the code; and there is a `jmp eax` right before it. `gdb` tries to disassemble the data bytes as if they were instructions, and anything after that is wrong. Is there a `g++` flag that would prevent that from happening?

Comment: Debugging optimized code is not for the weak of heart. Just use debug build for this.

Comment: It is not just one binary that I'm interested in; I want to prevent such interleaving of data and code inside a function.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this extreme desire to separate code and data?  Is it just that debugging issue?

Comment: When I was a child I wanted to be Moses and a programmer at the same time. This is the solution I came up with.

Comment: Joke aside, it meddles with the disassembly :D I need the instructions to be correct so that I can find static/dynamic calls in a project of mine.

Comment: For x86/x64, compiling with `-fPIC` should have the desired effect; although this is from some sketchy googling.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this could be an `XY` problem.  What you want, really really want is to convince gdb that the data bytes are data bytes, rather than convince the compiler to separate out data and code.

Comment: Mind you with the previous comment about finding static/dynamic calls it would probably make more sense to use something from the LLVM project

Comment: Petesh, -fPIC produces the same output.
PeterM, Finding jumps is a part of the project; let's just say that the function I am trying to disassemble should be mapped entirely to code.

Comment: It might be useful to give a simple code example and show the actual assembler output vs your (pseudo?) desired assembler output.  C++ switch statements work on constant expressions and I can't get my head around why/how you could **not** have that data embedded in the code.

Comment: It is a switch statement compiled with the -fpic flag, so it generates instructions such as `mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax+ebx*1-0x1a68]` (where ebx holds the instruction pointer obtained by `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx`). The problem is that the field it is trying to access (which is another offset for the next jmp) is stored *within* the code. That is what I am trying to prevent from happening; the switch code is just an example.